# Dúvidas sobre modos de instalação no Angular

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Vamos supor que quero instalar uma versão especifica de *bootstrap* no meu projeto angular, o comando seria esse:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 --save
```

Esse comando é necessário para que seja incluído no arquivo **package.json**, pois se algum dia esse projeto precise ser enviado para a nuvem o pacote do *bootstrap* será também será incluído e instalado, isso tudo por causa do parâmetro **--save**

Mas vamos supor que quero utilizar a biblioteca de *css* chamada **Bootstrap Switch**

[Bootstrap](http://bootstrapswitch.com/)

Não existem orientações de como instalar o projeto pelo parâmetro `--save`, a única forma de fazer funcionar as bibliotecas css seria colocá-lo diretamente no projeto, porém o arquivo package.json não seria notificado dessa inclusão no projeto, somente estaria instalada no projeto de forma manual.

A Biblioteca *Bootstrap Switch* está funcionando perfeitamente no projeto, já testei, mas será que na hora de enviá-lo para o servidor na nuvem ele vai funcionar?

Comment: Sim, vai funcionar. Mas vc olhou [esse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-switch) projeto no NPM? Se a dependencia que voce está usando não estiver no NPM, ou Bower, ou qualquer outro gerenciador, é necessário deixá-la fixa no projeto e não incluir no .gitignore. Se for fazer o deploy em uma cloud, será considerada.

Comment: não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Tem um projeto no NPM do http://bootstrapswitch.com/, perguntei se voce o viu. Pois é possível adicionar como dependencia da forma que supos não ter.